# Names for dynamically generated TestNG tests in Eclipse plugin

Tags: java, eclipse, testng

I converted a dynamically generated JUnit test suite to TestNG using a `@Factory` annotation. The tests are generated by scanning a directory that contains several test specification files  (written in a DSL) and by loading them in an test class that knows how to execute them. The test class has a single `@Test` method named `test`, implements `org.testng.ITest` and overrides `getTestName()` as recommended.

However, in the TestNG Eclipse UI, only the factory and a single execution of `test` is shown (although it is executed several times, as expected). With JUnit, I had the name of each spec listed as a separate test. This is very important because several test specs could fail and I would need to see all failures (which does not work in the TestNG Eclipse UI for me).

How can I achieve something similar with TestNG? I use the Eclipse TestNG plugin 6.7.0 and testng 6.7.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to generate tests with different names in TestNG?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2743676/how-to-generate-tests-with-different-names-in-testng)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try extending XmlTest in your test class and call setName(). I extended XmlSuite and used setName to name my "test suite" which is a class with multiple tests defined in it and that worked for me. In fact I just tried what I suggested on the same class and now it's called a test with the correct name. I'm not sure why the ITest interface is being ignored as I also tried that approach without success.

Comment: This worked for me, but the test names in the TestNG view were cluttered with additional information. I came up with a slightly different solution that addresses this (see my answer).

Answer (score 4):

As carlin.scott suggested, extending `XmlTest` works for this problem. However, I overrode `toString()` to return the test name (instead of calling `setName`). This has the advantage that the test name in the TestNG view is easier to read. By default, it contains additional information such as parameters and metagroups.