# How can I override the test method name that appears on the TestNG report?

Tags: unit-testing, testng

How can I override the test name that appears on the TestNG report?  I want to override the name that appears in the middle column (currently shows as the method name).  **Is this even possible?**

[image]

I tried to do it like this, but it didn't work.

```
public class EchApiTest1 extends TestBase {
  ...
@BeforeTest
public void setUp() {
    restClient = new RestClientPost();
    this.setTestName( "ech: XXXXXX" );
}
```

And, the base class:

```
import org.testng.ITest;    
public class TestBase implements ITest {        
    String testName = "";    
    @Override
    public String getTestName() {
        return this.testName;
    }           
    public void setTestName( String name ) {
        this.testName = name;
    }    
}
```

**NOTE: The above code does work when I am viewing the report detail in the Jenkins TestNG plugin report, which shows the overridden test name as a string called "Instance Name:" at the beginning of the Reporter log output.   Why, in this case, WHY does a "setTestName()" method alter a string labeled "Instance Name" in the report?**

One answer I found had a suggestion like this but I don't know how to pass an ITestResult arg to a AfterMethod method:

```
@AfterMethod
public void setResultTestName( ITestResult result ) {
  try {
    BaseTestMethod bm = (BaseTestMethod)result.getMethod();
    Field f = bm.getClass().getSuperclass().getDeclaredField("m_methodName");
    f.setAccessible(true);
    f.set( bm, bm.getMethodName() + "." + your_customized_name );        
  } catch ( Exception ex ) {
  Reporter.log( "ex" + ex.getMessage() );
 }
```

Thoughts?

Comment: Have you looked at [this](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/testng-users/K_BolH2tqh8) entry from the testng usergroup?

Comment: And [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15220262/custom-test-method-name-in-testng-reports) in Stackoverflow?

Answer (score 1):

Please find following code for set custom name of testcase in TestNG reports.

Following features are available in this code.

- Dynamic execution on same test-case in multiple time
- Set custom test-case name for reports
- Set parallel execution of multiple test-cases execution

```java
    import java.lang.reflect.Field;
    import org.testng.ITest;
    import org.testng.ITestResult;
    import org.testng.Reporter;
    import org.testng.annotations.AfterMethod;
    import org.testng.annotations.DataProvider;
    import org.testng.annotations.Factory;
    import org.testng.annotations.Test;
    import org.testng.internal.BaseTestMethod;
    import com.test.data.ServiceProcessData;

    public class ServiceTest implements ITest {

    protected ServiceProcessData serviceProcessData;
    protected String testCaseName = "";

    @Test
    public void executeServiceTest() {
        System.out.println(this.serviceProcessData.toString());
    }

    @Factory(dataProvider = "processDataList")
    public RiskServiceTest(ServiceProcessData serviceProcessData) {
        this.serviceProcessData = serviceProcessData;
    }

    @DataProvider(name = "processDataList", parallel = true)
    public static Object[] getProcessDataList() {

        Object[] serviceProcessDataList = new Object[0];
        //Set data in serviceProcessDataList
        return serviceProcessDataList;
    }

    @Override
    public String getTestName() {

        this.testCaseName = "User custom testcase name";
        // this.testCaseName = this.serviceProcessData.getTestCaseCustomName();
        return this.testCaseName;
    }

    @AfterMethod(alwaysRun = true)
    public void setResultTestName(ITestResult result) {
        try {
            BaseTestMethod baseTestMethod = (BaseTestMethod) result.getMethod();
            Field f = baseTestMethod.getClass().getSuperclass().getDeclaredField("m_methodName");
            f.setAccessible(true);
            f.set(baseTestMethod, this.testCaseName);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            ErrorMessageHelper.getInstance().setErrorMessage(e);
            Reporter.log("Exception : " + e.getMessage());
        }
    }}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I found a "workaround" but I am hoping for a better answer.  I want to be able to show this "test name" OR "instance name" value on the HTML report (not just within the Reporter.log output) and I am starting to think its not possible :

```
@Test(dataProvider = "restdata2")
public void testGetNameFromResponse( TestArguments testArgs ) {
    this.setTestName( "ech: " + testArgs.getTestName() );
    Reporter.log( getTestName() );  // this magic shows test name on report
    ....
```

With this workaround, the user can now identify which test it was by looking at the Reporter.log output but I still wish the name was more prominant.

I suspect the answer lies in writing a TestListenerAdapter that somehow overrides the ITestResult.getTestNameMethod()  method?   That is the holy grail I am looking for.

Answer (score 0):

The ‘result’  object  will automatically pass in the method   setResultTestName( ITestResult result )
Make sure you put  alwaysRun=true  like the following when you have groups defined in your test class otherwise “AfterMethod” will not be excuted.
@AfterMethod (alwaysRun=true)