# TestNG Using @Factory and @DataProvider

Tags: java, testing, selenium, webdriver, testng

I'm very new using TestNG and Java programming in general and I have a question in regards to using @Factory and @DataProvider together.

I want to test submitting a web form multiple times with different input data every time.

I have the following code:

```
public class SolicitudEmpleo extends LaunchBrowser { 

private String campoDni;
private String firstName;
private String lastName;

@Factory (dataProvider="dataProviderMethod")
public SolicitudEmpleo(String campoDni, String firstName, String lastName){
    this.campoDni=campoDni;
    this.firstName = firstName;
    this.lastName = lastName;
}

@DataProvider
public static Object[][] dataProviderMethod() {
return new Object[][] { {"000007", "Bill", "Gates"}, {"000008", "Stack", "Overflow"} };

}
```

When I run my test cases, the data provider will always use the last values contained in the array. For example, if I run the test now it will input the values: "000008", "Stack", "Overflow" into the web form and completely ignore "000007", "Bill", "Gates".

Thanks!!

EDIT: I printed all three Strings in the function:

```
@Factory (dataProvider="dataProviderMethod")
    public SolicitudEmpleo(String campoDni, String firstName, String lastName){
        this.campoDni=campoDni;
        this.firstName = firstName;
        this.lastName = lastName;

        System.out.println(campoDni);
        System.out.println(firstName);
        System.out.println(lastName);
    }
```

Console:

000007
Bill
Gates
000008
Stack
Overflow

EDIT 2: I'll post the entire code with the test cases so you guys can take a look and see if you can spot the mistake:

```
 public class SolicitudEmpleo extends LaunchBrowser { 

    private String campoDni;
    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;

    @Factory (dataProvider="dataProviderMethod")
    public SolicitudEmpleo(String campoDni, String firstName, String lastName){
        this.campoDni=campoDni;
        this.firstName = firstName;
        this.lastName = lastName;

        System.out.println(campoDni);
        System.out.println(firstName);
        System.out.println(lastName);
    }

    @DataProvider
    public static Object[][] dataProviderMethod() {
    return new Object[][] { {"000007", "Bill", "Gates"}, {"000008", "Stack", "Overflow"} };

    }


@Test (priority = 1)
public void testCase1() throws InterruptedException {

    Thread.sleep(3000);
    WebElement addButton = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='pt1:r1:0:b3_2']/a/span"));
    addButton.click();

}

@Test (priority = 2)
public void testCase2() throws InterruptedException { 

    Thread.sleep(5000);
    Select dropdown = new Select (driver.findElement(By.id("pt1:r1:1:s2:soc1A::content")));
    dropdown.selectByVisibleText("Dropdown");

    Thread.sleep(5000);
    WebElement campoDNI = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='pt1:r1:1:s2:it1::content']"));
    campoDNI.sendKeys(campoDni);

    WebElement verifyButton = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='pt1:r1:1:s2:b1']/span"));
    verifyButton.click();
    Thread.sleep(5000);

}

@Test (priority = 3)
public void testCase3() throws InterruptedException {

    WebElement firstNameElement = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='pt1:r1:2:it2::content']"));
    firstNameElement.sendKeys(firstName);

    WebElement lastNameElement = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='pt1:r1:2:it3::content']"));
    lastNameElement.sendKeys(lastName);

}

@Test (priority = 4)
public void testCase4() throws InterruptedException {

    Thread.sleep(2000);
    WebElement saveFormButton = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='pt1:r1:2:b12']/a/span"));
    saveFormButton.click();
    Thread.sleep(6000);

}   
  }
```

---

```
public class LaunchBrowser {

WebDriver driver;

@BeforeSuite()
public void launchBrowser() throws InterruptedException {
    System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "/Users/user/Documents/selenium-2.40.0/chromedriver");
    driver = new ChromeDriver();
    driver.get("http://webform.jsf");
    driver.findElement(By.id("pt1:pt_s1:itUsuario::content")).sendKeys("username");
    driver.findElement(By.id("pt1:pt_s1:itClave::content")).sendKeys("password");
    driver.findElement(By.id("pt1:pt_s1:itClave::content")).sendKeys(Keys.ENTER);
    Thread.sleep(5000);
}

 }
```

Also, the XML file for this test:

`<suite name="Parameter test Suite" verbose="2">
        <test name="Parameter Test one">
          <classes>
          <class name="test.classes.SolicitudEmpleo">
          </class>
         </classes>
       </test>
   </suite>`

Comment: From what I can tell, your code there looks good.  If you put a `System.out.println(campoDni)" in your `SolicitudEmpleo` function, what is printed?

Comment: I added the prints to the function and got the data in order: 000007
Bill
Gates
000008
Stack
Overflow

Comment: Then your factory and dataprovider are working.  The bug is somewhere else in the code.

Comment: I've posted the entire code with my test cases. Can you please take a look? Thank you!!!

Comment: Sorry, but that code isn't helpful. It won't be in your `@Test`s.  Can you show us the code in `LaunchBrowser` (Specifically, what you are doing with TestNG)?

Comment: I've posted the LaunchBrowser class with the XML file used to launch the test. Any thoughts? Thanks!!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Running the following code:

```
public class SolicitudEmpleo extends LaunchBrowser{
    private String campoDni;
    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;

    @Factory (dataProvider="dataProviderMethod")
    public SolicitudEmpleo(String campoDni, String firstName, String lastName){
        this.campoDni=campoDni;
        this.firstName = firstName;
        this.lastName = lastName;
        System.out.println("data number"+campoDni);
    }

    @DataProvider
    public static Object[][] dataProviderMethod() {
        return new Object[][] { {"000007", "Bill", "Gates"}, {"000008", "Stack", "Overflow"} };
    }
    @Test (priority = 1)
    public void testCase1(){
        System.out.println("Test 1");  
    }
    @Test (priority = 2)
    public void testCase2() throws InterruptedException { 
        System.out.println("Test 2 "+campoDni);
    }
    @Test (priority = 3)
    public void testCase3() throws InterruptedException {
        System.out.println("Test 3 "+firstName+","+lastName);
    }
    @Test (priority = 4)
    public void testCase4() throws InterruptedException {
        System.out.println("Test 4");
    }   
}
public class LaunchBrowser {
    @BeforeSuite()
    public void launchBrowser() throws InterruptedException {
        System.out.println("Launching");
    }
}
```

Produces the following output:

```
data number000007
data number000008
Launching
Test 1
Test 1
Test 2 000007
Test 2 000008
Test 3 Bill,Gates
Test 3 Stack,Overflow
Test 4
Test 4
```

Therefore, the problem is not with TestNG.  It must be something with WebDriver, and probably the site you are using.

Comment: Thank you for the help!! I really appreciate it. I guess i'll just use the @Factory annotation for my tests.

Answer (score 0):

Just to be sure, did you provide the testng.xml settings for your factory (http://beust.com/weblog/2004/09/27/testngs-factory/)?

Another way is this:

I am building my parametrized tests with the Annotation `@RunWith(Parameterized.class)` for my testclass and

```
@Parameterized.Parameters
public static Collection<Object[]> getTestData() {....}
```

...