# Create custom testng html report with browser name against method name

Tags: report, testng

I am working on cross browser testing and each of test methods in multiple classes run on 4 browsers Chrome, Firefox, IE, Safari.

The testng HTML reports & extent reports generated have the test methods in a column but I also need the browser name against each test method.

Even if the testng HTML reports would have the browser name against the test method would be great.

I found this [link](http://www.seleniumeasy.com/testng-tutorials/testng-customize-emailable-html-report-example) but I just need the browser column next to method column to custom report in the link

Comment: I don't think there's anything out there that can readily solve your problem. You will need to build your custom reporter to get this done.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24642711/set-testng-test-name-as-seen-on-the-html-report-dynamically-from-the-dataprovi). But it would be better to use reporting features for that e.g. you may pass any test name and description to report [see docs](http://extentreports.relevantcodes.com/java/#start-end-tests).

Answer (score 0):

You can do that by creating a customized `TestHTMLReporter` . Pass any data in your `CustomReport.java` class and generate your own report like below. I have also explained it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47309879/how-dataprovider-publish-the-test-data-into-html-report/47426325#47426325)

With your `customReport` You'd have to implement `IReporter` , extend `TestListenerAdapter` and override `generateReport` method if you want to implement a custom [`TestHTMLReporter`](https://github.com/cbeust/testng/blob/master/src/main/java/org/testng/reporters/TestHTMLReporter.java) . For other reporters you may have to do things a bit  differently but the concept will remain the same. You'd achieve custom 'TestHTMLReporter' like below .

Create a `CustomReport.java` file in your project and copy-paste the whole content of `TestHTMLReporter.java` , change the name of file in `getOutputFile` method  and it would look like below

```
public class CustomReport  extends TestListenerAdapter implements IReporter {

     @Override
        public void generateReport(List<XmlSuite> xmlSuites, List<ISuite> suites,
                                   String outputDirectory) {

        }
   ...
   //paste the content of TestHTMLReporter.java here
   ...
   ...
```

Make sure all your imports are in place from `TestHTMLReporter.java`
Now, in this file  change as per your requirement . For ex: if you'd like to add the end time of each of the test then at the correct place in `generateTable` method  add the below snippet

```
// Test class
      String testClass = tr.getTestClass().getName();
       long testMillis = tr.getEndMillis();
        String testMillisString = Long.toString(testMillis);
      if (testClass != null) {
        pw.append("<br>").append("Test class Name: ").append(testClass);

         // this line to add end time in ms
        pw.append("<br>").append("End Time(ms): ").append(testMillisString); 
        // Test name
        String testName = tr.getTestName();
        if (testName != null) {
          pw.append(" (").append(testName).append(")");

        }
```

Then you'll get like below

[image]

Now, You'll get two reports one with default and the other with your file name.
The only thing now remains is switching off the default reporting listeners, so you get only one report. For that you can follow [this](http://testng.1065351.n5.nabble.com/How-to-disable-a-specific-default-reporter-and-listener-td23194.html) or you may search for solutions. Hope this helps