# Creating Custom Method Names for testng HTML Report

Tags: java, selenium, ant, annotations, testng

I have a simple test suite (Very simple for this example). I am using the @Factory notation over the constructor and a @DataProvider which returns an object[][] of cities(as many as 100)I run my tests on. in this example there are 3 @Test methods. If I don't append the test names with the city name, I would have an HTML report that simply lists 3 test methods over and over with no way to distinguish them.

I have attempted this SO example: [Here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15220262/custom-test-method-name-in-testng-reports).

My test class works perfectly. The problem I'm having is that when I override the ITest getMethodName() I get unexpected output.

My Code:

```
@Test(sequential = true)
public class ParcelSearchPage implements ITest{

    private String cityClassName;
    private String cityName;
    private mTestCaseName = "";

    @Factory(dataProvider="getCities")
    public ParcelSearchPage(String className , String cityName){

        this.cityClassName  = className;
        this.cityName = cityName;

    }

    @DataProvider
    public Object[][] getCities(){
       
        return new Object[][]FromAnotherMethod();

    }

     @Override //from ITest
     public String getTestName() {
        return this.mTestCaseName;
     }

     @BeforeMethod(alwaysRun = true)
     public void testData(Method method) {
    
    this.mTestCaseName = String.format("%s : %s" , this.cityClassName, method.getName());
}

    @BeforeClass(alwaysRun = true)
    public void startup(){
         
        // init stuff
    }

    @Test
    public void test1(){

    }

    @Test
    public void test2{


    }

    @Test
    public void test3{

    }

}
```

I'm hoping this is detailed enough to get the example across.

Output:

Using cityClassNames Albany, Astoria, Bend

Opening the Html report I would expect a list as follows:

> Albany: test1
>
> Albany: test2
>
> Albany: test3
>
> Astoria: test1
>
> Astoria: test2
>
> Astoria: test3
>
> Bend: test1
>
> Bend: test2
>
> Bend: test3

I am forcing group_by_instance in the testng.xml

What I am seeing in the Html report is this:

> Albany: test1(Albany: test3)
>
> Albany: test2(Albany: test3)
>
> Albany: test3(Albany: test3)
>
> Astoria: test1(Astoria: test3)
>
> Astoria: test2(Astoria: test3)
>
> Astoria: test3(Astoria: test3)
>
> Bend: test1(Bend: test3)
>
> Bend: test2(Bend: test3)
>
> Bend: test3(Bend: test3)

I have spotted other post where folks have had similar problems (even the post I mentioned before hand)

I also tried this briefly in an @AfterClass method. The output was still problematic.

I don't understand how to rectify this. I've tested the string and the problem occurs in the getTestName() method. Even if I pass something simple like 'Hello' the Report will show Hello(Hello).

I think perhaps there could be a bug in the TestNG Java code.

Any solutions or guidance much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I came up with a hack that works pretty well when the @Test methods have no arguments.

I created a second data provider that simply returns an Object[] of the current city name. Then I just created a single String param for the city name in the test method and list the new data provider in the @Test notation. I removed the ITest interface altogether

So the output is now:

test1(Albany)

test2(Albany)

test3(Albany)

test1(Astoria)

test2(Astoria)

etc, etc

It isn't perfect but it works well for my needs.

Comment: Could you open an issue on https://github.com/cbeust/testng/issues with a sample that will allow us to reproduce and fix the ITest issue?

Comment: Sure I can do that